# MVC5 base controller that does setup of things that should always be done

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working with an MVC5 project. In this project I have a few things I always want to do in pretty much every response to the client.

For example, I always want to see if the user is logged in, and if so put the name of the user and their id into a the ViewBag variable for use in the .cshtml file.

I have a base controller which all other controllers inherit from. My first thought was to do these things in the constructor of that controller, but this does not work as the `User` variable does not exist yet.

Is there another way to do this, without calling a Setup() method in each Action?
Can I listen to some event that fires before an ActionResult is returned and insert my ViewBag data there?

Example of what does not work ;)

```
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected USDatabase _database = new USDatabase();
    public BaseController()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            var usr = _database.UserProfiles.Where(x => x.UserName.ToLower() == User.Identity.Name.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
            if (usr != null)
            {
                ViewBag.UserName = usr.UserName;
                ViewBag.UserId = usr.Id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My solution after reading the ideas in the answers below:**

Created an Actionfilter I triggered on the base controller.

```
public class UserDataFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    //OnActionExecuting – This method is called before a controller action is executed.
    //OnActionExecuted – This method is called after a controller action is executed.
    //OnResultExecuting – This method is called before a controller action result is executed.
    //OnResultExecuted – This method is called after a controller action result is executed.

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        var User = filterContext.HttpContext.User;

        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            using (var db = new USDatabase()) { 
                var usr = db.UserProfiles.Where(x => x.UserName.ToLower() == User.Identity.Name.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
                if (usr != null)
                {
                    var ViewBag = filterContext.Controller.ViewBag;

                    ViewBag.UserName = usr.UserName;
                    ViewBag.UserId = usr.Id;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Base controller now looks like this:

```
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
[UserDataFilter]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected USDatabase _database = new USDatabase();
    public BaseController()
    {

    }
}
```

And all my other controllers Implement the BaseController.

Comment: Did you try overriding the `Controller.OnActionExecuting` method and placing your code there?

Comment: I would suggest to make your BaseController abstract e.g. public abstract class BaseController : Controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes .. what you need is an **Action Filter**, action filters are .net attributes inherit from **ActionFilterAttribute** you can do what you specified using them, here is a link to understanding them and a few basic samples on what you do with them:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller(v=vs.98).aspx: THere are various Events you could use, depending on the exact circumstances.
For example: OnActionExecuting, OnActionExecuted